# Coderush Intellassist vs Intellisense

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, coderush

I'm using coderush with vs 2008. coding in VB.net.

I don't see any evidence of Intellassist, all i see is the usual VS intellisense.

Is this normal? Preferred? Do most people leave the defaults or do most/some turn off vs's intellisense?

Does intellassist somehow agument intellisence?

thanks
jonathan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see CodeRush Intellassist as an extension of Visual Studio Intellisense and not its replacement or anything else. Intellassist completes the text at the editor caret position with an in-scope identifier and may include other suggestions, such as physical file path completion or enumeration elements completion (which is not actual for Visual Basic).

To use Intellassist, just write code as you normally would. When Intellassist senses one or more suggestions matching the code you've entered so far, the best suggestion will be displayed to the right of the editor caret.

Once Intellassist is active, you have several options:

- Press Enter to accept the highlighted suggestion. If you have the case-sensitive option turned off, Intellassist will ensure the entire suggestion is properly cased to match the declaration.
- Press Shift+Enter to accept a portion of the suggestion. Shift+Enter accepts from the caret to the character preceding the next uppercase letter in the suggestion. For example, if "AllowMultipleSelections" was the suggestion, and "al" had been typed in, pressing Shift+Enter successive times would cause the selection to shift as follows:
- Shift+Enter is useful when you need to create a new variable name that is similar to a portion of an existing suggestion, or when you want to quickly access a different but similarly-named suggestion (differing only in the latter portions of the text). You can press Shift+Enter to move the selection right, and then start typing to get other suggestions.
- If more than one entry is suggested you can cycle forward and backward through the suggestions by pressing the Tab and Shift+Tab.
- Press the Delete key to cancel the suggestion.
- Do nothing for a few moments and Intellassist will hide the suggestion.
- If the text you've entered is a code template that you want to expand, just press Space or ; to expand the template normally.
- Continue typing (narrowing down the suggestion list or ultimately ignoring all suggestions).

Intellassist is highly configurable. You can specify whether case-insensitive suggestions should be made, and also change a host of other options.